# Ceiling joists/false ceiling

Tags: ceiling, joists, pole

I am trying to determine how my ceiling is constructed. I live on the top floor of a building built in the late 1800s/early 1900s.

Specifically, I want to know if my drywall ceiling is mounted directly to ceiling joists or if I have some type of false ceiling that does not contact the joists. I am thinking it is the latter case for the following reasons:

1. There is between 2 and 2.5 feet of space between the ceiling/roof (I drilled a hole in the ceiling and put a stiff wire up until I hit what I think it the roof)
2. I have "deep" sky lights (see pictures)
3. There is a patch of missing drywall on the ceiling in the closet that reveals a series of wooden planks that I suspect most of the drywall is attached to (see picture).
4. I've tried a variety of the usual methods to locate the ceiling joists without success (not that I am very good at this).

I ask because I am installing a pressure mounted (pole dancing) pole. It is a solid metal pole that extends when twisted (like a shower curtain rod) and is held in place by the pressure it puts on the floor/ceiling. The pole needs to be installed underneath a ceiling joints so it doesn't punch a hole through the drywall.

[image: Closet ceiling with exposed material]

[image: Sky light 1]

[image: Sky light 2]

[image: Sky light 3]

Comment: Based on the little I see, you don't have drywall, you have plaster.  Is your pole basically a tension rod?

Comment: Yes, it is a tension rod.

Comment: I'm not sanguine about a tension rod being suitable for this...do you have a link to the actual product?

Comment: The product itself is a tension rod. Here's a link: https://www.lupitpole.com/en/product/lupit-pole-classic-g2-standard-lock-black-45mm

There is an installation video too if that is helpful.

Comment: Smells like balloon framing with separate roof and ceiling framing. My first guess is that the roof and ceiling were framed independently to prevent roof deflections from cracking the ceiling plaster. Just speculating. In this scenario with a ceiling expected to get zero live load for all time, the framing behind the lath could be spaced ridiculously wide.

Comment: @popham but would it matter how wide the framing was, if the pole was located at a joist?  You'd have to hope the ceiling and floor are framed at the same spacing (or at least coincide) of course!  Still, I'd be happier with this type of pole in a structure with concrete floors and ceilings.

Comment: @Huesmann, under my theory, the ceiling is no good for this application. The joist hasn't been sized for the roof's live load, roof's dead load, and ceiling's plaster weight. It hasn't been sized for a habitable area's live load plus any dead loads. It's just sized for the plaster weight. I guess this thing inverts the loading and acts as a column, but I still expect it to make a mess of that brittle ceiling.

Comment: @popham oh, for sure—that's why I'd prefer concrete—the framing will flex and that plaster is toast.

Comment: Thanks for the information.